# How to Create php file to upload image to server in php for ios?

Tags: php, ios, web-services

I'm new to php. I don't know how to create webservice for image upload in iOS?

I tried from this tutorial : [image upload in ios](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2014/11/13/nsurlconnection-simple-upload-image-server-post-method/)

The php file is in above link.

Comment: please post your code here (at least the part that has mentioned in the error)

Comment: please check screen shot.i don't know exact error.i post error response in question

Comment: It is impossible to say what is the problem when we do not know what is your code. please examine the code and post important parts of it.

Comment: is php file to upload image is correct?

Comment: i also add referrence link.can you please check?

Comment: here, It is not proper to link to your code. you should select important parts of it and post them here.

Comment: i have not knowledge anout this.i refer this link to upload file.

Comment: my error gone when i change file permission.